# Шрифты Google Fonts не отображаются на мобильном устройстве

Tags: android, html, ios, мобильная-разработка, google-fonts

Здравствуйте, подключил к сайту Google Fonts, всё замечательно работает на ПК.

Но на телефоне шрифты не отображаются! Отображаются просто стандартные!
Помогите решить проблему.

Вот код на шрифты.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower|Lobster+Two|Lemonada:700|Neucha|Oswald');
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower|Lobster+Two|Lemonada:700|Neucha|Comfortaa" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Ну по этой информации сказать ничего нельзя. Либо вы неправильно подключили шрифты, либо еще что-то, без кода непонятно.

Comment: Да, что уж тут говорить про необычные шрифты на телефоне. У меня на айфоне даже Myriad Pro не отобразился.

Answer (score 1):

к импорту для кириллицы необходимо добавить `&subset=cyrillic-ext`

```
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower|Lobster+Two|Lemonada:700|Neucha|Oswald&subset=cyrillic-ext');
</style>
```